# Development dependencies in Dockerfile or separate Dockerfiles for production and testing

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm not sure if I should create different `Dockerfile` files for my Node.js app. One for production without the development dependencies and one for testing with the development dependencies included.

Or one file which is basically the development `Dockerfile.dev`. Then main difference of both files is the npm install command:

Production:

```
FROM ...
...
RUN npm install --quiet --production
...
CMD ...
```

Development/Test:

```
FROM ...
...
RUN npm install
...
CMD ...
```

The question arises because I want to be able to run my tests inside the container via `docker run` command. Therefore I need the test dependencies (typically dev dependencies for me).

Seems a little bit odd to put dependencies not needed in production into the image. On the other hand creating/maintaining a second Dockerfile.dev which just minor differences seems also not right. So what is the a good practise for this kind of problem.

Comment: I just wanted to say that here is all the Docker documentation. And none of it addresses testing. https://docs.docker.com/search/?q=test

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need to have different `Dockerfile`s and in fact you should avoid that.

The goal of docker is to ship your app in an immutable, well tested artifact (docker images) which is  identical for production and test and even dev.

Why? Because if you build different artifacts for test and production how can you guarantee what you have already tested is working in production too? you can't because they are two different things.

Given all that, if by test you mean `unit` tests, then you can mount your source code inside docker container and run tests without building any docker images. And that's fine. Remember you can build image for tests but that terribly slow and makes development quiet difficult and slow which is not good at all. Then if your test passed you can build you app container safely.

But if you mean acceptance test that actually needs to run against your running application then you should create one image for your app (only one) and run tests in another container (mount test source code for example) and run tests against that container. This obviously means what your build for your app is different for `npm` installs for your tests.

I hope this gives you some over view.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I got your point. My problem is to somehow inject the test source code and it dependencies into the image which holds the production/app code. So in my concrete case I could mount the node_modues (test dependencies) and the test source code into the container which holds the app. I can think of setting this up with a `docker-compose` config file. Does this seems to be the right direction to go? Disadvantage of this approach is that my tests will rely on the dependencies I injected into the container not the ones used in production.

Comment: That's seems OK, Docker and all processes are relatively new, so as long as you feel comfortable with the processes and don't produce more that one artifact at the end it should be fine. Please keeps your head up and search for new solutions and practices as things get more mature during time.

Comment: BTW, I'm using the procedure that I'm explained for production application and it works quite well.

Comment: I don't like it. test code in production is always a bad idea, and can lead to a security issues. I created a test docker file that with the production image as its base image + test files + mocha, and override the CMD to mocha. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Well then you'll have to support several `Dockerfile`s that are almost identical. Instead I recommend to use `NodeJS` feature like [production profile](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production). And another one recommendation regarding to

```
RUN npm install --quiet --production
```

It is better to create separate `.sh` file and do something like this instead:

```
ADD ./scripts/run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /*.sh
```

And also think about to start using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

#### UPD #1

By default `npm install` installs `devDependencies`. In order to get around this - use `npm install --production` OR set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` value.

Putting script line in separate file is a good practice in order not to change `Dockerfile` often. If you'll need changes next time then you'll have to update only script-file and you're done. In future you could also have some additional work to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please describe in more detail how the use of features like production profile would help me. I still will have two files, right? In regard to your second advice: Do you recommend to put the lines specific to the environments into a script and run this on build?